# How to find item in array using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

So I have this array:

```
var statuses = { New:1, Addressed:2, Rejected:3, Recovered:4, Billed:5, Completed:6 };
```

And I'd like to basically search the array for the "Rejected" key and have it return the value, so I can then go back/forth in the array as needed.

I've tried this, but it always fails with a "-1" saying it can't find it.

```
jQuery.inArray("Rejected", statuses)
```

Comment: What you have is **not** an array. It's a javascript object with many properties. Arrays are denoted with square brackets. Don't mistake those two different notions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"Rejected" in statuses;
```

No need for jQuery.

If you want the value, do:

```
statuses["Rejected"];
```

This will return `undefined` if "Rejected" is not in the object.

As the others have said, literals of the form `{blah: value, blah2: value}` represent objects, and those like `[value1, value2, value2]` represent arrays.

Answer (score 2):

That's not an array, that's an object.

It's a lot easier:

```
if (statuses.hasOwnProperty("Rejected")) {
  // It has it
  var valueOfRejected = statuses.Rejected

  // valueOfRejected now equals 3
} else {
  // It doesn't
}
```

You can safely retrieve the `Rejected` key, even if it doesn't exist in the Object without throwing an error; the retrieved value will just equal `undefined`.

Comment: If a property doesn't exist on an object, and you try to access it, there's no error thrown, it will simply produce `undefined` e.g. `({}).iDontExist === undefined;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var statuses = { New:1, Addressed:2, Rejected:3, Recovered:4, Billed:5, Completed:6 };

​$.inJsonObject = function(ind, obj)​​​ {

    return (typeof obj[ind] != 'undefined');

}​;

$.inJsonObject('Rejected', statuses); // true / false

​
```